# Link badges count to profile

Tags: feature-request, badges

On pretty much any Stack Exchange site, I when I click on my reputation count (next to my name, at the top of the page), it links to the reputation tab on my profile.

[image]

However, when I click on my badge count, nothing happens. I think that the badge count should link to the badges tab on my profile, similar to what happens when I click on my reputation count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would have to agree that this is quite unnecessary; however, I've been spending a lot of time working with Userscripts lately and thought I'd put one together real quick. If you install this in Chrome or Firefox with Greasemonkey, it will turn your badges into a hyperlink to the badges in your profile.

This is tested in Chrome, Firefox, Seamonkey, Midori, and Epiphany, and you're welcome to hack this to meet your needs. As an exercise, you could even add other links to the toolbar, like links to your favorites, questions, answers, tags, etc:

[IHaveBadges - A script to link your badges in the toolbar to your list of badges in your profile](https://stackapps.com/q/3759/4812)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is unnecessary since the badges summary can be viewed from the profile link, which is right next to it.

*Why would you want to place similar links at the very same position?*

Reputations are significant part of SE sites, which every member would like to keep in track of, but badge pages are not that frequently visited.

In my case, I get some badge, I take a look at it and that's it. Since you will be notified when you get a badge, there is very little need to keep track of badges.

But, if you really want to keep track of your badge progression, use http://data.stackexchange.com

Here is a [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=badge&order_by=popular) to a list of queries to check your badge progress.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's *necessary*. I just thought that it was a bit of a waste having the count there, but it does nothing when you click on it. Having both counts linked would improve consistency.